Server vs Client Side Rendering in NextJS
I'm developing a web app with a React Table and all the data to be returned can be retrieved from the server side, however, I'm not sure if the approach that I used is the best.
First, I was using a client component for the page, the page was sent, then a useEffect hook was used to fetch the data from a API Endpoint within my NextJS app, this Endpoint was just getting data from the database and returning it as a response, then, on the client side, after the response returns, a second endpoint outside the App was fetched and it's data is used to treat the database data, only after that a useState was filled and the table was loaded.
All other operations were done on the table, such as sorting and filtering.
Now, the way I'm trying to implement is this:
/**
 * Function to threat the data to be shown on the table, get the data received from the API for the tier list, then add the champion name and champion image to the object.
 * @param data: Object containing the untreated data fetched from the API.
 * @returns Array containing all the champions from the tier list after treatment.
 */
async function treatData(data: UntreatedData[]) {
  try {
    // Get the champion.json file for retrieving the champion name and image.
    const championsRes = await fetch(
      "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/14.6.1/data/en_US/champion.json"
    );
    if (!championsRes.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch champion data");
    }
    // Convert the response to json.
    const championData = await championsRes.json();

    //Creates the tier list data array, then
    const tierListData: TableData[] = data.map((data) => {
      // Search the array of values for the champion list to find the object with a subkey equal to the champion id.
      const key: any = Object.values(championData.data).find(
        (obj: any) => obj.key == data.champion_id
      );

      // Return the data for each row of the table.
      const rowData: TableData = {
        image_url: key.image.full,
        champion_name: key.name,
        individual_position: data.individual_position,
        win_rate: parseFloat(data.win_rate).toFixed(2) + " %",
        pick_rate: parseFloat(data.pick_rate).toFixed(2) + " %",
        pick_count: data.pick_count,
      };

      return rowData;
    });
    return tierListData;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

/**
 * Function to get the tier list data from the database and treat it.
 * @returns Returns the data ready to be used on the table after treatment.
 */
async function getData() {
  const DB = new db_ops();
  const data = await treatData(await DB.get_champions_tier_list());
  return data;
}

/**
 * Function to return the component with the tier list.
 * @returns React component containing the tier list data.
 */
async function TierList() {
  // Use State with the tier list data and the lane for filtering.
  const data: TableData[] = await getData();
  return <Table data={data} />;
}

export default TierList;

In this implementation all the data is treated with the data from the third party source (Which i can also get as a static file on the assets, since it doesn't change often) and it still maintains the original table interactivity since the  still a client component, with the passed data as substitute for the useState that get data from the API endpoint, but this code feels weird, there is any way to set the data on a client component before sending it without needing to create a server component and nesting a client one and passing the data?

It sounds good enough
